# R/Shiny WebApp logs, running in shell (Ubuntu crontab)

Tags: cron, log, webapps, r

I'm running, using crontab, an R/Shiny WebApp. The crontab expression looks like this:

```
@reboot R -e 'shiny::runApp(...)' | tee /var/log/shiny-server.log
```

I've also tried

```
@reboot R -e 'shiny::runApp(...)' &> /var/log/shiny-server.log
```

They both work, but they do the same: They print the header to the file when you initialize R from shell. But it doesn't print any text about the page, i.e. when it loads, when it uploads something, when it crashes...

Do you know how to pipe the output of the logs of the WebApp to the file?

Thank you

Comment: Well, it isn't the answer, but I found that using the `sink()` function inside R, makes the function to pipe out some `prints()` to a file. It's not solving the problem but it does something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make logs of `Rscript` function in terminal appear, I needed the following command:

`@reboot sh /home/admin/AutoRun.sh > /var/log/WebApp.log 2>&1 &`

And in the `AutoRun.sh` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
Rscript -e 'shiny::runApp(...)'
```